# Dompdf in local and vps?

Tags: php, codeigniter, centos7, dompdf

I have tried installing dompdf on laragon windows, it is already running normally.

this is my localhost specification

-Laragon   php 7.2.19
-normal phpmodule by laragon
-install dompdf 0.8.3 using composer

Then I moved all my projects to vps, and dompdf could not be run
when I open it it says 404

this is my VPS specification

- Centos7
- Apache
- php 7.2.25

I tried installing the dom and mbstring modules, but it still doesn't work

is this wrong about the settings in my codeigniter (but I run locally its fine) or php on my vps that has problems

Please help

Comment: Do you encounter Error?
please take screenshot from errors...

Comment: @Mehdi there is no text error, just what was in the automatic table there is a pdf download button, after being moved to vps the button is gone. then redirect the link to my pdf download to be not found 404

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem wass in `Mbstring`.

`bcs` in centos `Mbstring` is `autodisable` after install php at centos.

Lookup if Mbstring got disabled in centos.